# Let socket and http server listen to same port

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, httpserver

I make a website and it must have real-time communication to the server. With real-time I mean if a user vote on a topic, all connected clients must see the new average of the votes.

I've try something but I've got this **question**: How can I create a socket server and a HTTP server that listen to the same port with Node.JS? It I run code below, I've got this exception:

> Error: listen `EADDRINUSE`

Here is my server code:

```
let port = 8080;

const httpServer = require('http'),
      app = require('express')(),
      socketServer = http.Server(app),
      io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

httpServer.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('http server created on 8080');
}).listen(port);

socketServer.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on 8080');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. It doesn't make sense. TCP prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot in this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you want something similar to this:

```
const port = 8080;

let app    = require('express')();
let server = app.listen(port);
let io     = require('socket.io')(server);
```

This attaches an Express app and a `socket.io` server to the same HTTP server (which is returned by `app.listen()`). That's how you run both the app and the `socket.io` server on the same port.

Comment: How can two servers (http & socket.io) run on the same port? As far as I know, only one application/server can open on port  in a system. Could you please explain : Are httpserver & socket.io related or communicating to each other or independent app using same port? This is going above my head..

Comment: @OwlR `socket.io` uses Express's HTTP server to intercept and handle the specific requests it needs to function. So there's one HTTP server that is used by two application servers: Express and `socket.io`.

Comment: hmm.. not clear how intercept works but still got idea..httpserver should be communicating with socket.io to let it handle some function...may be looking into socket.io code may give some more detail

Comment: Hi, do you mind having a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets